# Create a bitmap and display it using Gtk# in C#

Tags: c#, macos, visual-studio, gtk#

I'm a MAC user so I can't use Windows Forms. I'm trying to figure out Gtk# myself but there is little to no tutorials and documentation to be found on the internet. I want to create a bitmap, draw something in it and display it. So far, I came with this and that displays a window:

```
 Application.Init();
 Window Win = new Window("Ray Tracing #2");
 Win.Resize(480, 480);
 Win.ShowAll();
 Application.Run();
```

However, I would like to manipulate with the window, so let's say: add a bitmap for a start.

I know that to create a bitmap I must write:

```
 System.Drawing.Image IMG = new Bitmap(640, 640);
```

but what then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All right, let's try to fix all the problems at once:

- You can find a [Gtk# tutorial in ZetCode](http://zetcode.com/gui/gtksharp/).
- If you are going to mess with graphics, then you need to know about [Cairo#](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/tools+libraries/libraries/Mono.Cairo/).
- I have a Github repository for my students with a [simple demo using both Gtk# and Cairo](https://github.com/baltasarq/GtkSharpDemo).
- I have another Github repository with a [CSV-based spreadsheet application](https://github.com/baltasarq/Colorado).

My advise is not to rely on the visual designer present in MonoDevelop/XamarinStudio, but to understand how the toolkit works and use it directly. Nowadays graphic toolkits are easy to use enough, and this way you are not tied to any editor/environment.

About your specific question, **Bitmap** pertains to the WinForms's universe (in fact, it is within the Drawing namespace), you should use a **Gtk.Image**. Let's create a scrolled panel (though it is called a "window"), and use it to show the bitmap.

```
var swScroll = new Gtk.ScrolledWindow();
var picBox = new Gtk.Image( "/path/to/image.jpg" );
var vbox = new VBox( false, 5 );

swScroll.AddWithViewport( picBox );
vbox.PackStart( swScroll, true, true, 5 );

this.Add( vbox );
this.ShowAll();
```

You can build an empty image with a specific size or whatever. Explore the constructors available for **Gtk.Image**.

Hope this helps!